# how to delete a text layer using fitz?

Tags: python, text-processing, pymupdf

This is a very straightforward issue. I added an invisible text layer using `page.insert_text()`.

After saving the modified pdf, I can use `page.get_text()` to retrieve the created text layer.

I would like to be able to eliminate that layer, buy couldn't find a function to do it.

The solution I've came up with is taking the pages as images and create a new pdf. But it seems like a very inefficient solution.

I would like to be able to solve this issue without using a different library other than fitz and it feels like it should be a solution within fitz, considering that `page.get_text()` can access the exact information I'm trying to eliminate

Comment: I use the term 'text layer' freely, understanding that pdfs are not meant to create different layers but to fix its info in a printable format. I guess that means once 'embedded', the inserted text can't be easily removed... but it still feels weird that I can access the text, see each character's position, and still not be able to remove it... I'm just an enthusiast anyway

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain of the whereabouts of your text on the page (and I understood that you are), simply use PDF redactions:

```
page.add_redact_annot(rect1)  # remove text inside this rectangle
page.add_redact_annot(rect2)
...
page.apply_redactions(images=fitz.PDF_REDACT_IMAGE_NONE)
# the above removes everything intersecting any of the rects,
# but leaves images untouched
```

Obviously you can remove all text on the page by taking `page.rect` as the redaction rectangle.

Comment: Is there a way to check if there is nothing to remove (except images) on this page?

Comment: @DemetryPascal - you can check for text presence like this: `text = page.get_text()`. If `text` is empty or only newlines, etc, then there is no text. Otherwise there may be vector graphics, which you can extract like this: `paths = page.get_drawings()`. Returns a list, so if empty, then there are graphics. That's about it.

Comment: Of course there may just be a bunch of spaces and / or newline characters, so you may want to do `text = text.replace("\n", "").strip()` and **then** check for emptiness.